# multiple checkbox with read more link in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular-material2

[Multiple checkbox with angular 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgwlW.png)

I have a scenario in angular 4 where 10 or more material checkboxes are there but i want to limit the checkbox upto 3 but when i click on "Read More" link then it should display all the checkboxes.
Please help in achieving this is angular 4?
Sample angular material code that i am using::

```
      <h3>Village(s)</h3>
  <md-selection-list #village value="village"> 
    <md-list-option *ngFor="let item of data.villages" [value]="item" (click)="submit(item)">
      {{item}}
    </md-list-option>
  </md-selection-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a class toggler and apply it to `<md-selection-list>`:

CSS:

```css
 .more {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 10rem // calculate height of md-list-option * 4
    }
```

HTML:

```html
 <md-selection-list #village value="village" [ngClass]="{'more': village.length > 4}">
```

Lastly, add a `span` or `div` element after `<md-selection-list>` for the read more link:

```html
<div (click)="village.classList.remove('more')">Read more</div>
```

Comment: the above code is not at all working...i want 4 checkboxes by default (in original state) and on click of "Read More", i want to display all the checkboxes.@simpleDmitry